# How to update values that are seperated in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
    index    material
    0        le verre
    1        les textiles
    2        le papier; le verre; les textiles
```

I want to update the **material** column so it becomes like this:

```
    index    material
    0        glass
    1        textile
    2        paper; glass; textile
```

I tried this but it changes the values without the `;` only

```
    d = {'le verre': 'glass', 'les textiles': 'textile', 'le papier': 'paper'}
    df['material'].replace(d)
```

as you see the third row has not been updated

```
    index    material
    0        glass
    1        textile
    2        le papier; le verre; les textiles
```

any idea?

Comment: pass `regex=True` : `df['material'].replace(d,regex=True)` ?

Comment: Yes, it worked! thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of possible solutions is:

1. Define a function:

   ```
    def replace_values(s, dct):
        for k, v in dct.items():
            s = s.str.replace(k, v)
        return s
   ```
2. Call it on your column, substituting the result under this column:

   ```
    df.material = replace_values(df.material, d)
   ```